# How can I align text to the right while using display inline block

Tags: display, text-align

I cannot use text align to move the pages in the navbar to the right while using display: inline-block.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_architect.htm

I want to only use display: inline-block to make a navbar like the one shown in this link (the logo to the left and the pages/links to the right)

Comment: You should post your code and describe what you have tried so far...

Comment: In addition, you can use your browser's developer tools to inspect your sample web page and figure out the necessary code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the page links in their own element and position that element absolute to the right.
In the snippet below I use a `<ul>` for the page links and position it to the  right.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul, li, a {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightslategray;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/"><b>BR</b> Architects</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```